# can we integrate android market application with our application

Tags: android

can we call pdf viewer application or any other 3rd patry application to our project/application? please provide your views and comments as its very important to me.
I want to develop application interating contents as document viewer, flash and animation
is android compatible with it??

please please provide me the details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if the other app responds to your intents. So instead of sending an explicit intent (`Intent i = new Intent(this,TargetClass.class)`) you would construct an intent that says "this is a PDF, anyone care to display it?".

If the 3rd party app is installed and understands this, it will be presented in a selection box from where you can pick it.

The following example shows how to do this for sending email:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
    String subject = getString(R.string.message_from_zwitscher);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
```

Have a look at the docs for [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and the [Intent and Filters guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html). There is also a site [Open Intents](http://www.openintents.org/en/) that is collecting information about usable intents.